# 2010 ford focus NO START

Tags: ford, starting, focus, ignition-switch

2010 focus SEL here lately i have had to push in hard and down to get to start and later stand on head with left leg up. No seriously about ready pull my hair out. i have replaced SWITCH on left side of steering wheel did not do any good so i bought a ignition switch and keyed it like my original so i could keep my keys.

Here is the kicker, it seems that the rod is not engaging the switch if i leave the switch out i can use a screw driver and put my key in cylinder and turn to on position and put screw driver in and turn it will start now i have made sure the switch is straight up n down.

So what is the secret to get this to work?

Comment: What country is this car from? That may help if it is a different configuration (e.g. right-hand drive vs left-hand).

Comment: I think what you're talking about is a known problem and you need to replace part of the column.